# Epoxy down shower drain (not pcv)

Tags: bathroom, epoxy, drains

I had an an epoxy shower floor done and some of it went down the pipes. So now, my shower drains super super super slow. I do not have plastic pipes mine are still the hard metal (lost the name of it at the moment).

I need to fix mine so that it drains ASAP as I'm trying to refinance the house and need the master shower to work!!!

Appreciate any feedback as my home is on a concrete slab and I don't have the time or money to have new pipes installed.

Comment: Budget the time, and make the people who poured epoxy down the drain deal with the money, as it's very much their mistake and they need to fix it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is on the money.  Sounds like some plumbing may need to be replaced.

Comment: If you have a cast iron drain pipe, they may be able to use a power auger with a cutter head to scrape the epoxy out, but it should _definitely_ be on the contractor who did the work. Leaving a partially blocked drain is unacceptable workmanship.

Comment: Are you **sure** this problem is due to epoxy? In my experience, the folks who apply epoxy coating are very careful *not* to get it inside the drain pipe. Also, the epoxy is like paint, very thin; it would take a lot of it to build up into a blockage. A regular hair clog is way more likely what you are dealing with. P.S.- epoxy can't be *dissolved* chemically so if that's what it is then mechanical removal is the only option (as suggested in prior comment).

Comment: Tagging on @JimmyFix-it it's common for contractors to put something in the drain to prevent things, like tools and debris, from falling in. Often this is an old rag such as part of a towel. On occasion it can be lost down the drain. Definitely don't jump to the conclusion that it's epoxy. A simple snake of the drain could fix the issue.

Comment: What's the question? Is the plumbing accessible? You'll need to tell us more about your project before we can help in any real way.